# Amortized analysis using potential function [Exercise from *Introduction to Algorithms*]

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I need some help with the following problem from *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein:

> Consider an ordinary binary min-heap data structure with $n$ elements that supports the instructions INSERT and EXTRACT-MIN in $O(\lg n)$ worst-case time. Give a potential function $\Phi$ such that the amortized cost of INSERT is $O(\lg n)$ and he amortized cost of EXTRACT-MIN is $O(1)$, and show that it works.

I'm not sure how to define the potential here. Especially since everything looks so "symmetric".

I mean, I get that one can only do as many EXTRACT-MIN operations as one does INSERT operations, and so if we have $k$ INSERT operations and $\ell$ EXTRACT-MIN operations total, then the time this takes is surely not bigger than doing the INSERT first and the EXTRACT-MIN operations later. And so I guess, the time for all operations is

$$
\begin{align}
t(k+\ell) &\le (\lg 1 + \lg 2 + \dots + \lg k) + (\lg k + \lg (k-1) + \dots + \lg (k-\ell+1)) \\
&= 2\lg k! - \lg \ell! \\
&= O(k\lg k)
\end{align}
$$

Hence we can assign $O(\lg k)$ to every insert operation and $O(1)$ to every EXTRACT-MIN operation (?).

So the result at least makes some sense. But I still don't know how to do it formally using a potential.

Thanks for your help! =)